# Asserting JSON JArray Api responses

Tags: c#, json, mstest, restsharp, web-api-testing

When asserting JArray Json responses, I am getting the error `Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray[,] Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray[,])>. Actual:<[ 1, 3]`

Can you please tell me where the error in the code is? I believe the issue is with the `ResponseReceived` class.

```cs
dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
var responseTarget = jsonResponse.target;

//create a new response expected object
var responseExpected = new ResponseExpected();

//create a new post response received object
var responseReceived = new ResponseReceived();
responseReceived.Target = responseTarget;

  //Assert
Assert.AreEqual(responseExpected.Target, responseReceived.Target);
```

```cs
    public class ResponseReceived
    {
        public JArray Target{ get; set; }

    }

    public class ResponseExpected
    {
        public JArray[,] Target{ get; set; } = new JArray[1, 3];
    }
```

```cs
//post request json
var myObject = new { 
    target = new []{ 5, 5 } 
    }
```

*UPDATE:*  The issue has been resolved using `public JArray Target{ get; set; } = new JArray(new[] { 1, 3 });`

*However* this seems to work with the majority of the test frameworks apart from **MSTest**.  How would this be resolved with MSTest?

Comment: Please [edit] and include input json (or relevant part of it)

Comment: @Aleks Andreev input JSON added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect that single `JArray` will be equal to array of `JArray`
Assuming your json looks similar to

```
{
  "target": [
    5,
    5
  ]
}
```

You can write asserion like:

```
var input = "{\r\n  \"target\": [\r\n    5,\r\n    5\r\n  ]\r\n}";
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(input);

var expected = new JArray(new[] {1, 3}); // not "new JArray[1, 3];"
var actual = json.target;

Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Comment: I get the error `'Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<[
  1,
  3
]>. Actual:<[
  1,
  3
]>.`  I would prefer to initialise the array value in the data classes above.

Comment: @CodeRocker Check it [online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NjqEKI). If you want to use your classes change `Target` type of `ResponseExpected` to `JArray` and assign it like in my code example

Comment: ok, so I changed it to  `public class ResponseExpected
    {
        public JArray Target { get; set; } = new JArray(new[] { 1, 3 }); ` but get the exception `{"Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<[\r\n  1,\r\n  3\r\n]>. Actual:<[\r\n  1,\r\n  3\r\n]>. "}`

Comment: @CodeRocker I'm using NUnit version 3.11 and it works fine. It looks like your testing framework compare actual and expected values by reference and not by content.

Comment: Could be.   I'm looking at the `Autos` properties  whilst debugging, and the only differences I can see are in the `Root` , `Parent`, `Path` Autos.  I'm assuming that's what's causing the issue?  All the other `Autos` properties are the same!

Comment: It works with `NUnit`.  I will clarify my question to be `MSTest` specific.

Comment: But I'm accepting this answer, since it worked.  Thanks @Aleks Andreev 

Comment: @CodeRocker you're welcome. I think you can create a new question with code that works with NUnit, tag it with [mstest](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mstest/info) and then maybe some expert in MS Tests come to that question and answer it